# How to scale several points with one inner point using python script?

Tags: python, transforms

I have several points' coordinate that constructed one polygon. I want to scale this polygon with a point inside the polygon and get points' coordinates after scaling.
[image: like this]

Comment: build-in addon: Mesh Tools > Offset Edges  
https://code.it4i.cz/blender/blender-addons/-/blob/4d7e6303a58cfa23c8580c06b6630324aeb06c9e/mesh_tools/mesh_offset_edges.py

Comment: @XY op is asking for how to do this via python, also asking how to get vert locs after the transform.

Comment: Not sure if the asker knows the coordinates of the geometric center.

Comment: @XY Yes the center coordinates is prepared.

Comment: @Winertoz Botawar So, did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: @XY not yet recently. But I think this won't be hard to deal, just need to spend some time to design...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

````
import pprint as pp
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

# object needs to be in edit mode for this exact
# technique to work. There are other ways to 
# get access to the vert data but this is
# one of the quicker ways.

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

# vector to scale the verts by
scale_amt = Vector((2,2,0))

vert_locs_current = [v.co for v in bm.verts]
pp.pprint(vert_locs_current)

#[Vector((-5.449918746948242, -3.937771797180176, 0.0)),
# Vector((2.550081729888916, -2.3869245052337646, 0.0)),
# Vector((-5.449918746948242, 4.062228202819824, 0.0)),
# Vector((2.550081729888916, 2.511380434036255, 0.0)),
# Vector((-8.69951057434082, 0.3733687400817871, 0.0))]

# loop through the vertices
for v in bm.verts:
    # scaling them uniformly is the same as just 
    # multiplying their current coordinates by a Vector
    v.co *= scale_amt
    
# this is so the new vert locations can be seen in
# the viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)

vert_locs_new = [v.co for v in bm.verts]
pp.pprint(vert_locs_new)

#[Vector((0.16568545997142792, 1.999999761581421, 0.0)),
# Vector((-1.8343143463134766, -1.827902167406137e-07, 0.0)),
# Vector((0.16568563878536224, -2.0, 0.0)),
# Vector((1.5798989534378052, -1.41421377658844, 0.0)),
# Vector((1.5798993110656738, 1.4142131805419922, 0.0))]
```
````

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/B4wq7Lo) is the before and after of my script overlaid over eachother, I think it's something to do with you script that's not related. Are you sure you're using `*=` and not *+=` anywhere you're manipulating coordinates?

Comment: Note that this script requires the object to be in edit mode.